# What does furnish means?

Tags: word-meaning

> Consequently, Euclid did not just furnish proofs; he furnished them
>   within this axiomatic framework.

I google "furnish", it comes up with [3 meanings.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=furnish&rlz=1C5CHFA_enCA780CA780&oq=furnish&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.2588j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

But seems none of them fit the case. I guess it means "finish" in this case, isn't it?

[Edit]  The second definition seems not to fit, because I thought "someone" is the subject, which refers to people, not an object.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the second definition, *"supply someone with (something); give (something) to someone."*?  Why do you think it does not fit this sentence?

Comment: Because I thought *someone* is the subject, which refers to people, not an object.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Yes, you can "furnish" things *to someone*, or just "furnish" them *in general*.  It's the same as "provide".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/furnish)) **Furnish** - meaning 2 - to provide someone with something that they need, especially information. For example, *Lyall’s evidence may have furnished police with a vital clue.*

This is the meaning which "furnish" has in your sentence. In other words, Euclid did not just *provide* proofs; he *provided* them within this axiomatic framework.